# How to stop Gitlab from occupying port 80?

Tags: gitlab

Gitlab is set up with this in gitlab.rb:

```
external_url 'https://git.mydomain.com:1443'
```

This works fine and it does work via port 1443.

The problem is that port 80 (which I need for another application) is still blocked as well, even though it is not needed at all.

How can I turn off all http services in gitlab and rely solely on https?

Other settings in gitlab.rb:

Nginx is commented out:

```
# nginx['enable'] = true
# nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
# nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 8080
```

Comment: In terms of network addresses and ports, "blocked" usually means that a firewall prevents access.  I think what *you* mean is that Gitlab is listening on port 80, and thereby preventing a different service from listening on that port.  (And for that to be useful, it must be that port 80 is *not* blocked, in the conventional sense.)

Comment: See my edit in the question

Comment: @John Bollinger: No, the firewall did not change, it somehow worked with the old version and the problem appeared only after a large update of gitlab

Comment: You misunderstand me.  I'm not suggesting that you can fix your problem by changing your firewall settings.  I'm saying that the wording you used to describe your problem is unconventional and misleading.  The only way I can make sense of what you said is that port 80 is *in use* (by Gitlab), and *not* blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configurations in the 'gitlab.rb' file. Have you activated the Nginx listener by any chance?.

Comment: See my edit in the question: It is commented out

Answer (score 0):

That your nginx settings are commented out does not speak directly to whether the bundled Nginx subsystem is enabled.  According to [its documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server), in fact, the Linux distribution of Gitlab bundles Nginx and *enables it by default*.

If you are running a separate web server on the same machine then **your best bet** is to enable HTTPS there, and use it in front of Gitlab instead of Gitlab's bundled Nginx.  The linked docs describe the Gitlab side of how to configure that, starting, but not ending, with ...

```
nginx['enable'] = false
```

.  There will be configuration needed on the external server side, too. The Gitlab docs speak to that a bit, but you might need someone with expertise in configuring the external server to help with integrating that.

---

As a possible **quick & dirty alternative**, it might work to configure the Nginx listen port in your Gitlab config to something other than port 80.  Maybe tp your HTTPS port:

```
nginx['listen_port'] = 1443
```

Or if that breaks HTTPS service then maybe a random other port would be better, say ...

```
nginx['listen_port'] = 8080
```